# fortran 77 nested do loop (multiplication)

Tags: fortran, fortran77

Part of my code is as follows

```
           else if (n .le.6) then   
          call DRNUN(6, XX)
             trun(j,1,n)=g1(j,1,n)/(cho(1,1)*1.0d0)
        do 7 l=2,n
         u(j,l-1,n)=DNORIN(XX(l-1)*(1.0d0-DNORDF(trun(j,l-1,n)))
     &       +DNORDF(trun(j,l-1,n)))
             do 17 m=1,l-1
              lemda(m,j,l,n)=cho(l,m)*u(j,m,n)
             print*, u(j,m,n),cho(l,m)!,lemda(m,j,l,n)
  17         continue
                totol(l,n)=sum(test(l,n,1:l-1))
            trun(j,l,n)=(g1(j,l,n)-tot(j,l,n))/cho(l,l)                 
  7         continue
```

when I run my whole program, it does not work.

I find the key question is on `lemda(m,j,l,n)=cho(l,m)*u(j,m,n)`. Values of u(j,m,n) and cho(l,m) can be printed out but not lemda(m,j,l,n).

If I put `lemda(m,l,n)=cho(l,m)*u(j,m,n)`, the code works. However, if I do not run my whole program, but only run this block of code with some assigned value containing `lemda(m,j,l,n)=cho(l,m)*u(j,m,n)`, all three values can be printed out. I could not figure out why my program stop working. Is that dangerous to increase dimension in the multiplication?

Comment: Welcome. Please take the Welcome [tour] to find out how to use this site. It is necessary to format your posts to make them readable. For Fortran questions always add the [fortran] tag.

Comment: Please never say "it does not work". Tell us what happens. Does it crash? Are there any error messages? How do they look like? Or are the results wrong? How wrong? Pleas show a larger piece of code. See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: Hi Stacy and welcome to Stack Overflow. We gladly help you out with this enigma, but it is hard for us to assess this partial piece of code. We are missing various pieces of information such as the declarations of the various variables. We do not require the full code, but just a minimized version which replicates the problem. You can create this by essentially starting to comment out/delete a lot of lines which are not needed and simplify a lot of lines, such as  `u(j,l-1,n)=DNORIN(XX(l-1)*(1.0d0-...` => `u(j,l-1,n)=0.0d0`.

Comment: continue: if all of a sudden things start to behave as you expect, you actually found the culprit yourself. If not, post the minimized working version here. It is called [mcve] as suggested by @VladimirF. Thanks a lot and looking forward to help you out. To edit your question, just click the word [edit] at the bottom left of your question.